# Guardar registros de una tabla en otra

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

Tengo un formulario con 2 elementos para guardar en dos tablas :

La primera parte muestra los datos de una cuenta (que se selecciono por id previamente y sus campos de la fila en la tabla estan dentro de la variable `$cuenta` :

```
<form method="post" action="{{route('cuentaStore')}}">
@csrf

<!---- parte 1 guarda en tabla cuenta ---->
<input type="hidden" value="{{$cuenta->valor}}" name="valor"/>
<input type="hidden" value="{{$cuenta->cuenta}}" name="cuenta"/>
```

en la segunda parte se muestra una lista de valores de la tabla `info` donde el `idcuenta` es igual al id de la tabla `cuenta`

```
    <!---- parte 2 guarda en tabla datos ---->
for // ciclo de la tabla info donde $idcuenta es igual a {{$cuenta->idcuenta}}

    <input type="hidden" value="{{$info->nombre}}" name="nombre"/>
    <input type="hidden" value="{{$info->telefono}}" name="telefono"/>

find del for

<button>guardar</button>     
</form>
```

si en lugar de ser

```
<!---- parte 1 guarda en tabla cuenta ---->
valor1
cuenta1
<!---- parte 2 guarda en tabla datos ---->
nombre1
telefono1

nombre2
telefono2
```

si no fuese por el ciclo for que genera la lista mi método de guardar el formulario en 2 tablas es asi

```
    public function cuentaStore(Request $request)
    {
$validatedData = $request->validate([
'valor' => 'max:255',
'cuenta' => 'max:255',            ]);

$cuenta = cuenta::create($validatedData); (este es el insert a la tabla cuenta, el $cuenta invoca a mi modelo donde crea un nuevo registro)

$validatedData2 = $request->validate([

'nombre' => 'max:255',
'telefono' => 'max:255',             ]);

$info = info::create($validatedData2);
```

Me gustaría saber si me pudiesen ayudar en como poder guardar en la tabla info, los registros correspondientes en diferentes filas

de antemano muchas gracias

Comment: porque no utilizas eloquent para eso? jugando con los modelos puedes lograr eso

Comment: Como dice el compañero de arriba, con el propio modelo puedes hacer atributos dinámicos. https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-mutators#accessors-and-mutators

Comment: es una lectura larga pero creo que es lo que estoy buscando, gracias!